# loading package error message - mac os x

Tags: r

I'm a relatively novice user trying to install package NMF_0.2.2.tar from the cran archive.

I'm getting an error message which seems to relate to machine architecture, and I'm not sure how to address it.
Searching here and on google didn't provide a fix.
The installation command and error message is below.

I'm running R version 2.15.2 under Mac OS X 10.6.8 on an Intel Core 2 Duo Macbook Pro.
I haven't heard back from the package maintainer, perhaps he's no longer available to maintain it which is why it's archived.
Any help would be appreciated as I have some older results from using this package and would like to finish that investigation.

## ------------------------------------------------

> sudo -E R CMD INSTALL ~/Downloads/NMF_0.2.2.tar
>
> - installing to library '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library'
> - installing *source* package 'NMF' ...
>
> ** R
>
> ** data
>
> ** inst
>
> ** preparing package for lazy loading
>
> Creating a generic function for 'residuals' from package 'stats' in
>   package 'NMF'
>   ** help
>
> *** installing help indices
>
> ** building package indices
>
> ** installing vignettes
>
> 'NMF-vignette.Rnw'
>   ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>
> *** arch - i386
>
> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'NMF', details:
>
> call: is.list(...)
>
> error: supplied argument name 'default.algorithm' does not match 'x'
>
> Error: loading failed
>
> Execution halted
>
> *** arch - x86_64
>
> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'NMF', details:
>
> call: is.list(...)
>
> error: supplied argument name 'default.algorithm' does not match 'x'
>
> Error: loading failed
>
> Execution halted
>
> ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x86_64'
>
> - removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/NMF'

Comment: `NMF` has been removed from CRAN. That's not the proximate cause of your problem, but it reason it was removed might be relevant to your problem. You might want to check out `NMFM` which is current and seems to do many of the same things.

Comment: Thank you. NMFN does do many of the same things. If I need to, maybe I can hack in the sparseness constraints that the old package had.

Answer (score 1):

I installed NMF 0.9 from the package author's repo (http://web.cbio.uct.ac.za/~renaud/CRAN/) on my Mac with R 2.15.1. It gave me an error message, "Error : package 'bigmemory' is not installed for 'arch=i386'", so I installed "bigmemory" package, then now it was installed fine.